# Subversion date range returning odd results

Tags: svn

SVN seems to have a very straightforward way to return information from a date range.  I was working on automating some of our deployment process, and I was trying to gather information from the SVN log. I tried this:

```
svn log --xml -r {2011-10-10}:{2011-10-11} https://somerepourl
```

this is what returned:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<log>
  <logentry revision="2531">
    <author>dio</author>
    <date>2011-10-07T00:09:54.070899Z</date>
    <msg>Updated targets file to use branch dependencies.</msg>
  </logentry>
  <logentry revision="2532">
    <author>dio</author>
    <date>2011-10-10T20:16:25.505299Z</date>
    <msg>Refactored Account Name validation.</msg>
  </logentry>
  <!-- etc etc -->
</log>
```

Now, the second result I expect, the date is within the range I requested, but the first result makes no sense to me, it's from several days ago.  I checked the svn docs, but it makes no mention of returning dates outside of your range.

Has anyone encountered this issue before?  I'm using SVN version 1.6.9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of `svn h log` says:

```
'{' DATE '}' revision at start of the date
```

It does *NOT* say: "first revision *after* DATE".

So, at 2011-10-10 00:00:00 the revision r2531 was "active", therefore it is shown.

Comment: Thanks, it took me a minute to grok what you're saying, but I get it now.

Comment: Hm. Sorry that I have my cryptic day ;-) How would you have formulated the answer - now that you know the meaning? I could edit/clarify the text so others can understand it better.

Comment: In retrospect it's very clear.  I was expecting that the date was a filter, but really what it seems to do is "convert" the start/end date into a start/end revision #, where the start revision number is the revision that the repo was at at the beginning of the date.  In this sense, I'm getting a history of svn states from a date range, not a history of svn commits from a date range.  I'm not sure how to state that succinctly, but that was my mental hang up.  Now that I realize what you were driving at, the document makes a lot of sense.